# Scan nmap through iptables restrictions

Tags: tcp, iptables, nmap

We need to find port on a server and read info from this port. If we will try to use nmap here - we will be banned. Because **iptables config, that blocks scans**. What nmap flags can we use for finding this port and not be banned?

first port iptables:

```
ipset create scanned_ports hash:ip,port family inet hashsize 32768 maxelem 65536 timeout 1

iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state INVALID -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m set ! --match-set scanned_ports src,dst -m hashlimit --hashlimit-above 1000/hour --hashlimit-burst 1000 --hashlimit-mode srcip --hashlimit-name portscan --hashlimit-htable-expire 10000 -j SET --add-set port_scanners src --exist
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m set --match-set port_scanners src -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -j SET --add-set scanned_ports src,dst


nohup python -mSimpleHTTPServer $_PORT > /dev/null &
```

second port iptables:

```
ipset create scanned_ports hash:ip,port family inet hashsize 32768 maxelem 65536 timeout 1

iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state INVALID -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m set ! --match-set scanned_ports src,dst -m hashlimit --hashlimit-above 1000/hour --hashlimit-burst 1000 --hashlimit-mode srcip --hashlimit-name portscan --hashlimit-htable-expire 10000 -j SET --add-set port_scanners src --exist
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m set --match-set port_scanners src -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -j SET --add-set scanned_ports src,dst

iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL SYN -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset --dport $_PORT

nohup python -mSimpleHTTPServer $_PORT > /dev/null &
```

Comment: It is unclear for me what you are asking. But it does not seem to be associated with programming at all, i.e. it is off-topic. It might be more on-topic at superuser.com and maybe [security.se]. But I think the questions needs to be more clear before reposting there.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because GENERAL IPTABLES SUPPORT IS OFF-TOPIC. Support questions may be asked on https://superuser.com. Use this tag only for questions on programming with iptables. Questions about configuring iptables should be asked on Server Fault (https://serverfault.com/tour).